# Send and Recive Payments With Credit Cards Only

Tags: paypal, payment, stripe-payments, balanced-payments, stripe.net

We are Making a App in which We Take Payments from Customers and Give Them Points
same like Customer can give Points to Us and Take Payment . This is a Game
is there any payment Gate Way That Directly Paid Customer in his/her Credit Card
we want Payments Direct Credit Cards To  Credit Cards
we will take customer credit cards when he will signup or later when he will give us points for Payment
Any Suggestion will be Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For PayPal, look at the following.

- [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) - This will allow you to hit somebody's credit card to process an amount without authentication so long as you've done a prior Authorization or Sale using the same credit card.  So you could have people run an Authorization on their card just to ensure it's good and get a transaction ID that you can use in future DRT requests.
- [DoNonReferencedCredit](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoNonReferencedCredit_API_Operation_NVP/) - This will allow you to load funds onto a credit card without referencing any previous transaction (so it's different than a refund.)  Keep in mind that when you send somebody money this way you won't get refunded fees like you would if you used the actual [RefundTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) API, so you may want to consider that.

You'll want to go through the detailed documentation for [Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/), of course, to get a good understanding of it.

You'll also need a [Payments Pro](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/referral/paypal-payments-pro?partner_id=UHALZ2245EDV6) account to be able to process credit cards directly and utilize these features.

If you happen to be working with PHP I'd recommend using my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).  It'll make the API calls very simple for you.

Comment: Nice Thanks .what about Stripe?

Comment: Stripe makes you wait 7 - 10 days (or more) for your money.  That could cause issues with what you're explaining you're trying to do I would think.

Comment: i read from stripe doc they transfer fund  only in USA any other cool payment gate way  that allow me to transfer funds through CC to CC?

Comment: are you sure we can transfer funds to customer?DoNonReferencedCredit  have nothing param to transfer

Comment: DNRC allows you to push funds to a credit card from your PayPal account.